# Fade div in when other div has faded to a 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have four div's with different text size.
I want to fadeIn 4 divs, but a div may only fadeIn when the previous div is fully visible.

```
$('.MESSAGE_CONTAINER:last').hide();
$('.MESSAGE_CONTAINER').each(function(index) {
        if($(this).text().length > 50){
            delayNumber = 2500;
        }else{
            delayNumber = 800;
        }
        $(this).delay(delayNumber*index).fadeIn(200);
});
```

Above is my code but I'm unsure about how to use the :visible with the :nth-child part. 
I've tried the following:

```
if($('.CONTAINER:nth-child(index)').is(':visible')){
     $(this).delay(delayNumber*index).fadeIn(200);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fadeIn` takes a second argument which is a callback that will be called once the element has been faded in. Here's an example how you could leverage this and a helper function:

```js
function fadeInNext($divs, delay, index) {
  index = index || 0;
  if (index < $divs.length) {
    $divs.eq(index).fadeIn(delay, fadeInNext.bind(this, $divs, delay, index + 1));
  }
}

$('div').hide();

fadeInNext($('div'), 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>div1</div><div>div2</div><div>div3</div><div>div4</div>
```